# JQgrid jqGrid('getGridParam','data') - How do I return the back to controller with JSON mapped to object?

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jqgrid

jqGrid('getGridParam','data')

provides a javascript array with (index,person json)..

```
result= $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
$.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url : "savePerson",
                                data:  JSON.stringify({list:result}),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                headers:{
                                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                                },
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function(response){
                                    console.log(response);
                                },
                                error: function(jaqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
                                    console.log(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                                },
                                fail: function(jaqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow){
                                    console.log(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

how do i pass this back to the controller?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String savePerson(Model model,
            @RequestBody Map<String, Person> list)
```

for some reason

it keep return a map with key="list" and JSON of persons